# How to edit content center data (Inventor 2018)?

Tags: autodesk-inventor

Example: I want to use an M8x20 bolt in Inventor and edit the data of the file to get it right in BOM. I was able to do it in Inventor 2017 and earlier but not any more. I have tried to untick "read only" in the content center properties etc. Any suggestions? 
[image]

Comment: *"content center data inventor 2018"* Huh? What?

Comment: Yes, I mean the data of a part, e.g the title and description of a bolt. It cannot be changed any more as an error pops up as soon as I click "apply" after editing it.

Comment: Looks like it is not checked out to you. I am using inventor 16 and don't have any trouble as long as it is checked out.

Comment: I have also used previous Inventor versions (2015-2017) and have not had any problems with it.